# Django 2.1.3/SQLite : UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id || while trying to access my superuser account

Tags: python, django

i am working on a website that has a social appeal and i have to create an AbstractUser Model to store extra info about the users; while doing so, i ran into this error while trying to log into django admin page with my superuser account.

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id.
```

i have rebuilt the project 3 times and the issue still occurs.

here's my models/forms/signals/admin.py files

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class UserModel(AbstractUser):

    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        path = self.image.path
        img = Image.open(path)
        if img.height > 500 and img.width > 500:
            output_size = (500,  500)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(path)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import UserModel, Profile

class UserModelCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = [
        'username',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'email',
    ]

 class UserModelChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
        ]

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'image',
    ]
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django.conf import settings
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import UserModel, Profile
from .forms import UserModelCreationForm, UserModelChangeForm

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(UserModel)
class UserModelAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserModelCreationForm
    form = UserModelChangeForm
    model = UserModel
    list_display = [
        'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
    ]

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

i have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserModel'` to **settings.py**

i have added `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'` to **users/__init__.py** to automatically create profiles.

i have added `def ready(self): import users.signals` to **apps.py**

all i am trying to do is access my superuser account. i have created 7 different superusers (just to check) they all raise the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the signals are redundant. Only one signal should be fine, it should be like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: what if a user tried to update his details ? wouldn't i need a function for that too ?

Comment: Well, the one to one field is already tied to the user. so it won't change(with user updated) unless you forcefully change it.